# My HP Monitor has a lock sign and hole behind it. Display is blank when turned on. How do I unlock it?

Tags: display, lock

HP LA1956X Monitor. 
When connected to a laptop , power light comes on blinking, but display is blank

Comment: A picture of the issue would also help out here. the Lock sign with a hole seems to me to be a kensington type lock slot but it's hard to decipher without a photo

Comment: Probably something in the OSD (on screen display) menu, download you user manual and enter the OSD menu and see if there is a lock setting in there.>>>>>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-compaq-la1956x-19-inch-led-backlit-lcd-monitor/5219467/manuals

Comment: Manual can be found here: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03462402.pdf  Looks like maybe, you are talking about a cable lock found on page 18 of the user manual?

Comment: Maybe your laptop needs to be set to turn on the monitor, the FN key + [?] monitor key?

Answer (score 2):

## 1. LOCK ON MONITOR

> **My HP Monitor has a lock sign and hole behind it**

That's just a physical attachment point for a security cable that you can use to secure the monitor to a desk or other fixed object. It slows down thieves.

[image][image]

You can ignore this - it isn't relevant to your problem

---

## 2. OUTPUT-SELECT ON LAPTOP

> **When connected to a laptop , power light comes on blinking, but display is blank**

Some laptops don't automatically select an external monitor. Often you have to tell the laptop to use the external monitor by a special key-combination on the keyboard

- typically the <kbd>Fn</kbd> together with a key on the top row that has an extra "monitor" icon on the front face of the keycap.
  [image][image][image]
- On windows 10 you might try <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

---

## 3. INPUT-SELECT ON MONITOR

Some monitors have multiple input connectors - perhaps two HDMI ports, maybe a DVI *and* a VGA input connector. Most monitors with multiple input connections will automatically select whichever is active. However, it *may* be worth using the menu button on the monitor to bring up the On-Screen Display (OSD) menu and selecting the input from there.

[image][image]

Comment: Wow... very thorough and complete answer to a very incomplete answer. Kudos to you, @RedGrittyBrick.